# Puting files on array in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

How to put files of directory in an ArrayList.

```
public void findFiles(String path) {
    ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();

    for (File objects : files) {
        if (objects.isFile()) {
            list.add(objects);
        }

        //goes to the deeper layer
        if (objects.isDirectory()) {
            findFiles(objects.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

But all information of ending files adds to list(0).
The next step will by finding of duplicates, and I want to do it with comparing of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method just updates a local variable, which is lost once the execution is completed. You should return it somehow, so you can aggregate the results, e.g.:

```
public List<File> findFiles(String path){
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
    for(File objects : files) {
         if(objects.isFile()) {
             list.add(objects);
         }
         //goes to the deeper layer
         else if(objects.isDirectory()) {
             list.addAll(findFiles(objects.getAbsolutePath()));
         }
     }
     return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the recursive call, because you are calling a `void` method. You are also not setting values in any object that is accessible outside of the method.

If you do neither of these things, then the results of your recursion step will never be saved anywhere and there is no point in the recursion.

The proper way to do recursion is either to pass down an object reference which every step down will fill and then it will be full once all the recursion steps return, or to return a value and then join the returned values together with the current step's value.

I'll give an example of the first possibility:

```
public void findFiles(String path, List<File> listToFill){
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
    for(File objects : files) {
         if(objects.isFile()) {
             listToFill.add(objects);
         }
         //goes to the deeper layer
         else if(objects.isDirectory()) {
             findFiles(objects.getAbsolutePath(), listToFill);
         }
     }

}
```

In this case, you have to call it from the top level (or main) by first initializing the list, and then passing it down (assuming your method has defined `path` to the path of the top directory, and `obj` as the object that has the `findFiles` method (you didn't tell us its name).

```
List<File> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

obj.findFiles( path, listOfFiles );
```